# Using the Decorator Pattern in a PHP application

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am getting to a point in my application where there seems to be a lot of presentation logic in my models:

```
<?php foreach ($this->users as $user): ?>
    <span class="phone">
        <?php echo $user->getPhoneNumberFormattedAsText(); ?>
    </span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

At first, I started approaching this as a need for View Helpers:

```
<span class="phone"><?php echo $this->userPhone($user->getPhone()); ?></span>
```

However, I've started running into a problem where I have lots of little View Helpers that are specific to certain models, that don't need to take up an entire file. It would be nice if I could group this presentation logic together and keep it out of the model. I think this is when the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) makes sense.

> "The decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows behaviour to be added to an existing object dynamically."

I have seen a few examples online, but no real, practical examples of code. I would like to know if you have successfully used this pattern in your PHP application and what a PHP example of this should look like.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a decorator pattern for my php application. Basically it's a wrapper class to a xml configuration file where I define my basic needs. To simplify I use a pizza as an example. Then I have a class for each ingredient and wrap it around the other class. In the end I call the prize method of each class and it gives me the sum of everything.

```
$order = new pizza($xml_file);
$order = new add_salami($order);
$order = new add_cheese($order);
$order = new add_tomato($order);   
$order = $order->prize();
```

You need to maintain a pointer to the current object in every ingredient class. When you call the php new function you can use it to backup the current object. It's a bit like a linked list (of objects). Then you can call the prize() method of the last object and loop through all other classes. But to decorate you need to add new classes. You can also replace the $xml_file with a start value. I've all my decorator class in one file. A decorator class can looks like this:

```
class add_salami {

    protected $order;
    protected $prize;

    public function __construct ($order) {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->prize = $order->getPrize();
    }

    public function getPrize() {
        return $this->prize + 10;
    }
}
```

I keep many of these tiny decorator classes in a huge file.

Comment: I've added an example. I think you need also to call the getPrize function in the constructor of each decorator class. The do-something is some of my method I need for the salami decorator. The tx_decorator class itself it's just an empty interface class. I'm not sure if you need it. My example works also without it.

Comment: You can replace tx_salami with add_salami. I hope you know what a constructor does? Anyway that's what I want to say.  I'm out.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing your code sample. I hope you dont mind and that I conveyed your original intent. Let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: Well, it's php 4. And not php 5. You don't need to change that?

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework uses the decorator pattern for its form elements. Imagine having an input element with type="text". You could 'decorate' this element with a label, divs, fieldsets, etc.

Comment: I am already using Zend Framework, so I'm not sure what you are trying to imply. Also, the ZF implementation of form decorators is sort of a black box and it's not clear how it is all working. Also, I'm not really sure how it compares to "decorating" a model for displaying in a view script and how using this decorator would look like in my view script.

Comment: I'm not trying to imply anything. You asked for practical, real-world examples of the decorator pattern. ZF is open-source, how is it blackbox?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. Yes, Decorator pattern can help you to reuse your classes in even different business logic.

I use decorator patter everywhere possible because it can realy help you. For example, lets say you want to get list of records from database and for this you are using simple repository. which will return you all or one record. like here. For more about repositories go here.

```
$repo=new ClientRepository();
$repo->all();
```

But, lets say you have business rule that in some places you should log requested data and in other places you should cache request. So, what you will do. Of course majority will create seperate class for CacheClientRepository and LogClientRepository. It may be ok, but what if business rule will ask you Log and Cache at the same time so what will you create seperate class like LogAndCacheClientReposiotry(); If you do like this you will end up with tons of class that repeat code inside.

For this case the best solution is to use DecoratorPattern. You you will need to create one interface and implement it in every decorator. You can decorate your repository as much as you want.

Here is code sample:

```
 <?php

interface RepositoryInterface
{
    public function all();
}

class ClientRepository implements RepositoryInterface
{

    public function all()
    {
      // Your code for database goes here
    }
}

class CacheRepository implements RepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RepositoryInterface
     */
    private $repo;

    /**
     * CacheRepository constructor.
     * @param RepositoryInterface $repo
     */
    public function __construct(RepositoryInterface $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        //Code for caching goes here

        return $this->cache('cache-all',function(){
            return $this->repo->all();
        });
    }
    //......
}
class LogRepository implements RepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RepositoryInterface
     */
    private $repo;

    /**
     * LogRepository constructor.
     * @param RepositoryInterface $repo
     */
    public function __construct(RepositoryInterface $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        //Code for logging goes here

        return $this->log('log-all',function(){
            return $this->repo->all();
        });
    }
    //......
}

//.. Simple Repository
$repo=new ClientRepository();
//.. Cached Repository
$repo=new CacheRepository( new ClientRepository() );
//.. Logging Repository
$repo=new LogRepository( new ClientRepository() ) ;

//.. Logging and Caching at the same time
$repo=new LogRepository( new CacheRepository( new ClientRepository() ) ) ;
```

I hope it will help you, beacuse decorator pattern is one of best patterns that I know.