# Decorator Pattern Issue

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, decorator

I am using a decorator pattern to add style and options to an output stream (console).

> It's an console app that adds color to the command line output. The
>   decorator adds the color. The condition in the **ClientClass** is that
>   **if an error** occurred then decorate with **red text** and **if no error** occurred then decorate with **green text**. The color
>   decorator therefore has optional calls that only the **ClientClass**
>   can know about.
>
> * Copy of the OP's comment on one of the answers

The problem I have is this:  I am passing in my decorator to a class via the constructor.  But the decorated object requries that I call two methods that are not in the base class i.e. that being decorated.

Is this bad?  Shouldnt i only be calling those methods which are available in all decorated classes?

As an example:

```
<?php

abstract class MyAceBaseClass
{ 
    abstract function doYourThing();
}


class MyAceBaseClassDecoratorA extends MyAceBaseClass
{ 
    protected $aceBaseClass;

    protected $amount = 0;

    public function __construct($aceBaseClass)
    { 
         $this->_aceBaseClass = $aceBaseClass;
    }

    public function doYourThing()
    {
        $result = $aceBaseClass + $this->amount;
        return $result;
    }

    public function decoratorFunctionA()
    {
        $this->amount = 10;
    }

    public function decoratorFunctionB()
    {
        //----
    }
}

class ClientClass
{ 
    private $aceObject;

    public function __construct(MyAceBaseClass $aceObject) 
    {
         $this->aceObject = $aceObject;       
    }

    public function run()
    {
         if ($someCondition) {
             $this->aceObject->decoratorFunctionA();
             $this->aceObject->decoratorFunctionB();
         }

         $result = $this->aceObject->doYourThing();

         echo $result;
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the client class needs to call decoratorFunctionA and decoratorFunctionB (which are only availble in the decorator class) before it can call the abstract method doYourThing() available to all classes extending MyAceBaseClass.  This feels wrong.

I think the decorator implementation is correct but now i am stuck with this other problem

How can i resolve this?

The client class might not need both decoratorFunctionA() and decoratorFunctionB() called, it might only need 1 or none so I cant simply call these automatically in the doYourThing call.

A possibility is to have an interface for MyAceBaseClassDecoratorA but then i am kind of defeating the purpose of using the decorator in the first place.

Comment: Look at this [example with real world code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232888/using-the-decorator-pattern-in-a-php-application/47411421#47411421).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call methods not specified by the **interface** you're expecting: `MyAceBaseClass` (as @ctrahey pointed out).

Also, if I read it correctly, you seem to be mixing the things up. **Who's decorating who in this case?**

If the purpose of the **Decorator Pattern** is to add functionality to an existing object without subclassing (in other words, without saying that an object "is a"), the decorator must have a protected property with the decorated object. It seems like that it's your `ClientClass` that's decorating what you called `MyAceBaseClassDecoratorA`.

IMO, it should be something along this lines:

```
// Concrete object
class MyObject implements MyObjectInterface {
   public function doSomething() {
       return 1;
   }
}

// Your abstract decorator
abstract class MyObjectDecorator implements MyObjectInterface {
    protected $myObject;

    public function __construct(MyObjectInterface $object) {
        $this->myObject = $object;
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        return $this->myObject->doSomething();
    }
}

// Your concrete decorator
class MyConcreteObjectDecorator extends MyObjectDecorator {
    public function doSomething() {
        $value = $this->myObject->doSomething();
        return $value + 10;
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**

As for your explanation in the comments, here's what you should do:

```
class ClientClass {
    // ...
    public function run() {
        $this->aceObject->doYourThing(); // and that's all
    }
    // ...
}
```

So, you'll not call `$this->aceObject->decoratorFunctionA();` or `$this->aceObject->decoratorFunctionB();` outside of the decorator as you have done in the `ClientClass`.

**Instead, you should provide the decorated object with the functionality injected into the `doYourThing()` method** before calling the `$ClientClass->aceObject->doYourThing()` method.

If there's an error, then you'll decorate it with the `RedTextDecorator`, if everything went well, than you'll, instead, decorate it with the `GreenTextDecorator`.

```
public function run()
{
     if ($error) {
         $this->aceObject = new RedTextDecorator($this->aceObject);
     } elseif($success) {
         $this->aceObject = new GreenTextDecorator($this->aceObject);
     }

     $result = $this->aceObject->doYourThing();

     echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keyne.  I do have it implemented as you discribed but i left that out of the example for some reason sorry.  I have updated my question to show you.  You can see the the result depends on a decorated function being called - ultimately from the client class as its optional i.e. a client might not need to add ten

Comment: I'm still confused: `But the decorated object requires that I call two methods that are not in the base class` That's why you need to implement those calls in your concrete decorator `doYourThing()` method, as I said.

Comment: But the calls are optional and based on a condition only the client knows about was what i was trying to get at.  I have updated the question again to reflect this

Comment: In this case you need to provide the implementation details so that we can understand your architecture and see which pattern fits better. So far, all I can say is that this is not a job for the decorator pattern, it must have the same interface as the object being decorated.

Comment: My implementation is basically identical to what you see.  Its an console app that adds color to the command line output.  The decorator adds the color.  The condition in the client is that if an error occurred then decorate with red text and if no error occurred then decorate with green text.  The color decorator therefore has optional calls that only the client can know about

Comment: Check the updated answer and see if it answers your question.

Comment: ah ok, so you suggest we have a decorator for both error and success.  That could work, i was combining it into one class that handled adding color to the console text. so it had a method to addColor($color)  so it should be more fine grained than that then?

Comment: Well, IIRC, you're using Decorators to avoid changing the `text` class, which is responsible for printing the text. Since the purpose of Decorators is to decorate existing functionalities, **you cannot decorate the object interface** with a `setColor` method. If this is the case, then you need to follow something similar to what I've proposed.

Comment: This is impossible - "Instead, you should provide the decorated object with the functionality injected into the doYourThing() method before providing it to the ClientClass constructor"  - because the client is the only code that knows if an error occurred.  Therefore it must then instantiate a new error or success decorator before calling the doYourThing  and the second option means the client must know about the specific decorator types which is defeating the purpose

Comment: Okay, so as it does not fit injecting it decorated on the constructor (I've edited it on the question), you should go with the second option, with the `if($somecondition)`. As for your comment about that, if we take your example on your answer, then there's no difference between having to know about the decorator specific interface or having to know about the available decorators. Also read this: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DecoratorPattern maybe you could do it in another way.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I just wanted to check one last thing: do all decorators have to be compatible with each other in as much as they should all be able to wrap each other.  In this example the decorators dont make much sens if applied together

Comment: Yes, they must be compatible. It does not make sense to wrap your `TextObject` with a `RedTextDecorator` and then wrap it again with the `GreenTextDecorator`, you'll not need to do such thing anyway. But maybe, after making the text red by decorating it, you decide to decorate it again with a `ToUpperCaseDecorator` and then a `BoldDecorator`. Just a naive example.

Comment: Ok thanks again, essentially then if i have only a need for red and green decorators then im using the pattern wrong

Comment: I think it's fine to have both decorators and your default text object without color (terminal default). If you want to continue the discussion, please, call me on the php chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php maybe someone can analyze it with mode details.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if your constructor takes MyAceBaseClass, it should never call methods on it which are declared in one of it's descendent classes. If the $aceObject class will *always* be a decorator, then make an interface for it and ONLY call methods on it which are declared in the interface, that's what interfaces are for. It can be helpful to "boil it down" to one clean method, and delegate the responsibility of knowing what specific methods to call to the decorator.

I might mention, however, that I prefer my decorators know more about their subject than the subject know about it's decorators. An object's relationship to it's decorators should be as loosely coupled as possible, hopefully to the point that it simply knows that it can be decorated (i.e. implements a "decoratable" interface or something similar such as implementing an observation mechanism which interested decorators can observe). However, what a decorator *does* know about it's subject should be exclusively through an interface.

Comment: Thanks - is knew this was an issue as it felt wrong to be calling these methods. Can you see a potential solution here?  Would creating an interface iMyAceBaseClassDecoratorA be a solution?  The thing is though, what if i introduce another decorator

Comment: Without knowing more about your domain, it's hard to say what is best. For instance, if your ClientClass knows that it's $aceObject will be a decorator, then I would say make a decorator interface which `MyAceBaseClassDecoratorA` implements (ideally only one method), and use that interface for your type-enforcement in the constructor, and only call that one method from inside ClientClass (note that `MyAceBaseClassDecoratorA` can call more methods on itself).

Comment: Each decorator has specific things it can do in addition to the base class.  So maybe im missusing the decorator and another pattern would be best here.  I am learning oop and its so difficult finding the correct pattern for things :(

Comment: patterns are most effective when well-combined. For instance, the decorator pattern is more effective with some kind of one-to-many delegation pattern, such as composite or observer; depending on your style/preference. Either way, there is one-to-many, either you say "I have one decorator (though you are using the composite pattern to have that one know how to trigger the rest)" or "I have this one *event*, but many observers who might want to do something about it"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it simple you can use  decoratorFunctionA() and decoratorFunctionB() inside doYourThing method based on condition (Whether you want to add color or not). In this way your contract will remain the same and you can get desired functionality.

If you wan to make it more clearer then maybe you can use two different decorators.

For more details you can refer this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern