# is this a decorator pattern (PHP)?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I was watching a Lynda.com PHP Design Patterns tutorial when the tutor presented this solution to a challenge:

index.php:

```
include_once 'decorator.php';

$object = new Decorator();
$object->sentence = "This is a sample sentence that we're going to manipulate in the Decorator.";

// This should output: this is a sample sentence that we're going to manipulate in the decorator.
echo $object->lower();

// This should output: THIS IS A SAMPLE SENTENCE THAT WE'RE GOING TO MANIPULATE IN THE DECORATOR.
echo $object->uppercase();
```

decorator.php:

```
class Decorator
{
    public $sentence = '';

    public function lower()
    {
        return strtolower($this->sentence);
    }

    public function uppercase()
    {
        return strtoupper($this->sentence);
    }
}
```

Why is this a decorator pattern? All I see is the instantiation of an object and accessing two of the objects methods.

Comment: At this level of the class it is absolutly useless indeed, but if you start expanding it it can get more and more complex, and specialized to text manipulating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you posted is not a decorator, it simply provides a new interface (`lower` and `uppercase`) on top of a string. A decorator adds behaviour without changing the underlying interface.

A typical example of decorators is literally decorating graphical elements. For example:

```
interface Shape {
  draw();
}

class Rectangle implements Shape { ... }
class Circle implements Shape { ... }

class BorderDecorator implements Shape {
  Shape shape;

  draw() {
    shape.draw();
    drawBorder();
  }
}
```

All of the classes above have the same interface, so if a function needs a `Shape`, you can pass in a plain old `Rectangle` or you can wrap it in a `BorderDecorator` to get a rectangle with a border.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is not a decorator pattern. You just created Utility class for string if you really want to convert your utility class into decorator then just see below:

```
<?php

interface StringInterface
{
    public function string();
}

class StringDecorator implements StringInterface
{
    private $text;

    public function __construct($text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }
    public function string()
    {
        return  $this->text ;
    }
}


class StringLower implements StringInterface
{
    private $text;
    public function __construct(StringInterface $text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }
    public function string()
    {
        return strtolower( $this->text );
    }
}
class StringUpper implements StringInterface
{
    private $text;
    public function __construct(StringInterface $text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }
    public function string()
    {
        return strtoupper( $this->text );
    }
}
class StringTrim implements StringInterface
{
    private $text;
    public function __construct(StringInterface $text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }
    public function string()
    {
        return trim( $this->text );
    }
}

// For Lowercase
$decorator=new StringLower( new StringDecorator("Text") );
// Output: Lowercase Text to text
$text=$decorator->string();

// For Uppercase
$decorator= new StringUpper( new StringDecorator("text") );
// Output: Uppercase text to Text
$text=$decorator->string();

//TO normalized text from " TeXT " to text.
$decorator= new StringTrim( new StringLower( new StringDecorator(" TeXT ") ) );
// Output: normalized text from " TeXT " to text also extra space removed from left and right.
$text=$decorator->string();
```

This are your case examples If you need more real world example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232888/using-the-decorator-pattern-in-a-php-application/47411421#47411421), I gave here good example from real world.