# Structuring Decorators in PHP

Tags: php, python, decorator

I'm sort of a novice developer trying to expand my toolbox and learn some more tricks. I recently came across a pattern in Python called "decoration" and I was wondering if/how I could implement this in PHP as I have an existing PHP code base.

Here is a short example of what I mean:

```
import time

def log_calls(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        now = time.time()
        print("Calling {0} with {1} and {2}".format(
            func.__name__,
            args,
            kwargs
        ))
        return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Executed {0} in {1}ms".format(
            func.__name__,
            time.time() - now
        ))
        return return_value
    return wrapper

@log_calls
def test1(a,b,c):
    print("\ttest1 called")

@log_calls
def test2(a,b):
    print("\ttest2 called")

@log_calls
def test3(a,b):
    print("\ttest3 called")
    time.sleep(1)

test1(1,2,3)
test2(4,b=5)
test3(6,7)
```

It doesn't necessarily have to be that syntactically pretty; I understand that all languages have their nuances and I know PHP does not support that syntax. But I still want to be able to achieve the same effect while rewriting as little code as possible.

Comment: good luck with that , but basically decorators are functions that return functions you can call later, so if you can return a function in php you should be able to do that, take a look at : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func.php too.

Answer (score 2):

Basically no, it's not supported in PHP in any way at all. As far as I know, it's not even on the roadmap for future PHP versions.

Of interest, and slightly relevant: The closest I could think of in PHP-land to what you're after is if you use phpUnit to test your code. phpUnit implements something along these lines for its own use, using references in docblock type comments above a method. eg:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider myProviderFunc
 */
public function myTestFunc($argsFromProvider) {
    ....
}

public function myProviderFunc() {
    return array(....);
}
```

Thus, when phpUnit wants to call `myTestFunc()`, it first calls `myProviderFunc()`, and passes the output of that function into `myTestFunc()`.

This strikes me as being close to, but not quite the same as the decorator syntax you're describing. However, it's not standard PHP syntax; phpUnit implements all of this stuff itself. It reads the source code and does a load of pre-processing on as it parses the comment blocks before running the tests, so it's not exactly efficient. Suitable for a unit testing tool, but not for a production system.

But no, the short answer to your question is that what you want can't be done in PHP. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has no syntactic support for the decorator pattern, but nothing really hinders you from implementing it yourself.

You can look into the following discussions, which might be relevant to your question:

- [how to implement a decorator in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948443/how-to-implement-a-decorator-in-php)
- [Trying to implement (understand) the Decorator pattern in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360650/trying-to-implement-understand-the-decorator-pattern-in-php)

Here is another resource, with UML diagrams and code samples in multiple languages, including PHP.

- [Decorator Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator)